# How to detect ANY Internet Explorer in PHP?

Tags: php, internet-explorer

The question is, how to detect any IE version using PHP?

I seen PHP scripts that detect specific versions of IE, but I was unable to find a way to detect *any* version of IE. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The concept is the same for all of them.  And, why would you want to do this anyway?

Comment: http://bit.ly/1f141cz

Comment: *khm*-*khm* INCLUDING THE IE11

Comment: Advice: Do not do it. Just accept that browsers have their quirks. If you absolutely need to target IE then use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html). Targeting browsers for special treatment is more trouble than it is worth.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
function ae_detect_ie()
{
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && 
    (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
?>
```

taken from : http://www.anyexample.com/programming/php/how_to_detect_internet_explorer_with_php.xml